# How to handle relative path when calling the function from other folders in python?

Tags: python, path

## the Problem

- I have a readtxt(path) function in readTool.py from Folder A.

```
# inside a .py file in Folder A
def readtxt(path):
    flat_matrix = np.loadtxt(path, skiprows=0, comments='#')
    return flat_matrix
```

- I use this function in Folder B with a relative path (path is based on **Folder B**).

```
# run from Folder B
matrix1 = readtxt(a_relative_path_in_B)
```

- But the readtxt function read a file with the relative path based on **Folder A**.

## the Question

- So how could I avoid such misunderstanding if I consist to give the readtxt(path) function a relative path?

Comment: Could you please post some code snippets? It would help contextualize the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python always uses folders relative to the location of the script that is ran, so you're encountering normal behavior. To avoid these issues it is easiest to use absolute paths, these can universally be shared between scripts run from different folders:

```
import os
working_dir = os.getcwd()
absolute_path = os.path.join(working_dir, "a_relative_path_in_B")
matrix1 = readtxt(absolute_path)
```